# Omitting types and Baire category

Tags: gn.general-topology, model-theory

What is the relation between omitting types theorems in model theory and the baire category theorem?

Comment: If you read Spanish, you may want to try and get a copy of Julián Mariño's Undergraduate Thesis at the Universidad de los Andes in Bogotá, which is on essentially this question. I have a copy *somewhere* on a pile at my office.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, found the thesis.

What you can prove is that the omitting types theorem follows from the Baire category theorem. I haven't thought about whether the other direction holds in the sense of reverse mathematics.

One starts by fixing a signature $\tau$, and assigning an appropriate topology to the space $\mathcal E_\tau$ of $\tau$-structures. This is a proper class, but the topology has a set-sized basis, so arguments can be formalized in a straightforward fashion.

The topology of elementary classes is defined by picking as a basis the classes of the form $M_\tau(\phi)$ for $\phi$ a $\tau$-sentence. Here, $M_\tau(\phi)$ simply denotes the class of $\tau$-structures that satisfy $\phi$. Similarly, if $\Phi$ is a set of sentences (a theory), then $M_\tau(\Phi)=\bigcap_{\phi\in\Phi}M_\tau(\phi)$ is the class of models of $\Phi$.

This topology is not quite metrizable, but admits a [uniform structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space): A basis of uniformity is attained by considering the relations $\equiv_\Phi$, where $\Phi$ varies over the finite sets of $\tau$-sentences, and two $\tau$-structures $\mathcal M$ and $\mathcal N$ are $\Phi$-equivalent, $\mathcal M\equiv_\Phi\mathcal N$ iff for each $\phi\in\Phi$, we have that $\mathcal M\models\phi$ iff $\mathcal N\models\phi$.

As a consequence, $\mathcal E_\tau$ is regular and (if $\tau$ is countable) it is pseudo-metrizable, with pseudo-metric $$d(\mathcal M,\mathcal N)=\inf\{1/n\mid\mathcal M\models_{\Phi_n}\mathcal N\},$$
where $\phi_1,\phi_2,\dots$ enumerates the $\tau$-sentences and $\Phi_n=\{\phi_i\mid i< n\}$.

Notoriously, the space is complete (every Cauchy net converges to an ultraproduct of the members of the net) and compact (and logical compactness can be seen as a consequence of this).

The topological version of the omitting types theorem then takes the following form:

> **Theorem.** Let $\tau$ be a countable signature, and let $T$ be a consistent theory in this language. Let $C$ be a countable set if constant symbols, disjoint from $\tau$. Let $\Sigma(x)$ be a $1$-type in language $\tau$. If for all $c\in C$ we have that 
>    $$ M_{\tau\cup C}(T\cup\Sigma(c))$$ 
>   is closed nowhere dense in $M_{\tau\cup C}(T)$, then there is a (countable) model of $T$ that omits $\Sigma(x)$.

The point is that $T$ locally omits $\Sigma(x)$ iff for any $c\in C$, the open class $M_{\tau\cup C}(T\cup\Sigma(c))$ has empty interior in $M_{\tau\cup C}(T)$. The key to this argument is that if $\tau'$ expands $\tau$, then the projections 
 $$ P_{\tau'\tau}:\mathcal E_{\tau'}\to\mathcal E_\tau $$
(that map $\tau'$-structures to their restrictions to $\tau$) are uniformly continuous.

This can be used to give an essentially topological proof of the omitting types theorem, as a consequence of the Baire category theorem, as follows: Letting $\phi(x)$ vary over all $\tau\cup C$-formulas in one free variable $x$, define
 $$ X=\bigcap_{\phi(x)}\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N}M_{\tau\cup C}(\exists x\phi(x)\to\phi(c_i)). $$
The important properties of $X$ are that it is a dense $G_\delta$ subset of $\mathcal E_{\tau\cup C}$, the projection $P_{\tau\cup C,\tau}\upharpoonright X:X\to\mathcal E_\tau$ is continuous, open, and onto, and 
 $$ X=\{\mathcal M\in\mathcal E_{\tau\cup C}\mid\{c^\mathcal M\mid c\in C\}\mbox{ is the universe of an elementary substructure of }\mathcal M\}.$$

Letting $X(T)=X\cap M_{\tau\cup C}(T)$, we have that $X(T)$ is dense in $M_{\tau\cup C}(T)$, so each $M_{\tau\cup C}(\Sigma(c_i))\cap X(T)$ is closed nowhere dense in $X(T)$, and therefore a $G_\delta$ in the compact regular space $M_{\tau\cup C}(T)$. Therefore $X(T)\cap\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N}M_{\tau\cup C}(\Sigma(c_i))$ has empty interior and its complement in $X(T)$ is dense (so, relevant for us, non-empty). If $\mathcal M$ is *any* structure in this complement, then for each $i$ there is a $\sigma_i(x)\in\Sigma(x)$ such that $\mathcal M\models\lnot\sigma_i(c_i)$. So, using the key property of the space $X$, the elementary substructure of $\mathcal M$ with universe the $c_i^\mathcal M$ is countable, and omits $\Sigma(x)$, completing the proof.

The pretty idea of considering $\mathcal E_\tau$ as a topological space is classical. One can see some of it in the book on **Models and ultrapowers** by Bell and Slomson. Another early reference is

> Andrzej Ehrenfeucht, and Andrzej Mostowski. *A compact space of models of first order theories*, Bull. Acad. Polon. Sci. Sér. Sci. Math. Astronom. Phys., **9**, (1961), 369–373. [MR0148536 (26 #6043)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=148536).

Modern attention to this topological approach comes from the work of Xavier Caicedo, who saw its usefulness in the setting of abstract logics. See for example his three papers

> *Compactness and normality in abstract logics*, Ann. Pure Appl. Logic, **59 (1)**, (1993), 33–43. [MR1197204 (93m:03062)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1197204),
>
> *Continuous Operations on Spaces of Structures*. In **Quantifiers: Logics, Models and Computation**, pp. 263-296, Synthese Lib., 248, Kluwer Acad. Publ., Dordrecht, 1995,
>
> and
>
> *The abstract compactness theorem revisited*. In **Logic and foundations of mathematics (Florence, 1995)**, pp. 131–141, Synthese Lib., 280, Kluwer Acad. Publ., Dordrecht, 1999. [MR1739865 (2001b:03039)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1739865).

The specific presentation I sketched above comes from Julián's undergraduate thesis, written under the supervision of Xavier Caicedo:

> Julián Mariño Von Hildebrand. *Topología en los espacios de models de la lógica de primer orden*, Undergraduate thesis, Dept. of Mathematics, Universidad de los Andes, Bogotá, 1995.

(Julián is a friend from many years ago, and I haven't talked to him in ages. Thanks, I think I'll use this question as an excuse to give him a call.)

Comment: An unhappiness of the argument is that I do not see a "mostly topological" way or arguing about some of the properties of $X$, and instead must invoke a Henkin-style construction.